# EndRead failed with Xamarin.Forms HttpClient

Tags: httpclient, xamarin.forms

I define the httpClient using ModernHttpClient

```
var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;
```

And then use the same httpClient instance for several requests

```
  var result = await httpClient.GetAsync("someaddress");
```

This request fails sometimes but not always with IOException with message.
 "EndRead failed". What is the general cause for this exception? Is the connection closed before its done or what? The code is running on Android.